# makefile generate file object for the header file only?

Tags: c++, makefile

im having probleme in `makefile`.
when i execute `make` commande in the terminal it has to generate `header.o`  and `main.o` and then combine them to generate the excutable `kmeans.o` file,but it did not, it only generate `header.o` which is `km.o` and stop without any error message.

## this is my make file :

```
CFLAGS = -ggdb
DEFINES = -DDEBUGGA
INCLUDES = 
LIBS = -lstdc++
EXAMPLE = kmeans.o
CC=g++

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(DEFINES) $(INCLUDES) $<

all::   km.o kmeans.o 

km.o:   km.cpp km.hpp
gnuplot_i.o:    gnuplot_i.hpp
kmeans.o:   main.cpp

kmeans: $(EXAMPLE)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $(EXAMPLE) $(LIBS)

clean: 
    rm -f $(EXAMPLE) kmeans
```

The `km.cpp` and `km.hpp` is the header file and it implementation.
`gnuplot_i.hpp` is header with its implementation.
`main.cpp` file the file which links all these libries.

Answer (score 0):

The default target in this makefile is `all: km.o kmeans.o`.

So when you run `make` that is what will run. So make will create those two `.o` files and stop.

If you want `make` to be the same as `make kmeans` then you need `all: kmeans` as your default rule or to move the `kmeans` target above the `all` target (since the first target is the default one).